# Show custom message only on sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to figure out how I can show a custom "Welcome back" message in my view when a user signs in within my application.

I am currently using Devise to handle all of this and I can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Flash**

You'll want to [use the `flash` system](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) to create a "notice" that will be fired on the `sessions#create` controller of Devise:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :user, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" } #=> add extra method to your sessions controller

#app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb
Class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   after_action :welcome_message, only: :create

   private

   def welcome_message
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome Back"
   end
end
```

This allows you to create a "Welcome Back" message, which will be inserted after the `create` method in your `SessionsController`. Nothing is overwritten in `Devise` - you're just adding a flash message after the user signs in

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid using flash messages? I want to use a totally different styling to my usual ones. I thought about setting a variable like @show_welcome_message = true and checking for it in the view but no such luck unfortunately