# Rails - How to Change Devise Welcome Message Depending on Attribute Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my Rails 5 app, I'm using Devise for my `User` model (not using Confirmable with Devise).  What I need to do is to replace the existing flash message after a `User` is created with a different flash message depending on the `country_code` value for the `User`.

For example,

```
# after the user is successfully saved
if @user.country_code == 'CA'
  flash[:notice] = "You're in Canada!" 
else
  flash[:notice] = "You're international!"
end
```

I checked [Devise's documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki), but couldn't figure out how to create two different versions of a successful sign up message.

The closest I could I find were messages related to new sessions:

[Show custom message only on sign_in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198772/show-custom-message-only-on-sign-in)

[Dynamic Flash Messages in Devise](http://mczuchnowski.github.io/blog/dynamic-flash-messages-in-devise)

How can I alter Devise's standard code to create a variable welcome/success message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After user is created, Devise will call `after_sign_up_path_for` method to know where to redirect to. You can change flash message by override this method.

```
class RegistrationsController <  Devise::RegistrationsController
  ...

  protected
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    # after the user is successfully saved
    if resource.country_code == 'CA'
      flash[:notice] = "You're in Canada!" 
    else
      flash[:notice] = "You're international!"
    end

    super
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Generate the devise controller:**

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

This will generate all devise controllers in **app/controllers/users** directory.

**Add the below route in routes.rb:**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registrations'}
```

**And then, override the `create` action to show flash message as you needed:**

Instead of `set_flash_message!` you can set `flash[:notice] = "You're in Canada!"` as you wish.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

...
...

# POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up # Here you need to set your flash message
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" # Here you need to set your flash message
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

...

end
```